# null given on bundle in fragment from MainActivity

Tags: java, android

i have some problem from a bundle ..

[MainActivity.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mtu8.png)

An this is a log from the MainActivity ..

[Log user in MainActiviy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj10d.png)

This is a fragment get Bundle

[FragmentChat.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKhzE.png)

And this is some log on FragmentLogin

[Log in FragmentChat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsyYt.png)

Sorry bad engglish ..

Comment: Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
LoadFragment(fc);
```

not

```
LoadFragment(new FragmentChat());
```

since you set the arguments bundle on `fc`.